# How to execute cli tool from your Flutter app on Mac OS?

Tags: flutter, macos, dart

in the following code:

```
final Directory dir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
final binaryPath = '${dir.path}/MyCliTool';

// Copy binary from assets to the temporary directory (if not already copied)
if (false == await File(binaryPath).exists()) {
      final ByteData binaryBytes = await rootBundle.load('bin_assets/MyCliTool');
      await File(binaryPath).writeAsBytes(binaryBytes.buffer.asUint8List(), flush: true);
      // Make the binary file executable (for Unix-like systems)
      await Process.run('chmod', ['+x', binaryPath]);
}
// Run the binary
ProcessResult result = await Process.run(binaryPath, ['arg1', 'arg2']);
```

I have the following error on Mac OS:

```
Exception has occurred.
ProcessException (ProcessException: Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not planning to publish your app, you can disable the App Sandbox entitlement `com.apple.security.app-sandbox`  (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/app_sandbox) by setting it to `false` in your entitlements file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

To fully understand how entitlements work, i suggest you to give a peek at these resources:

1. https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/macos/building#entitlements-and-the-app-sandbox
2. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements